# Excel 2013: Is there a way to delay processing a filter until multiple columns have their criteria set?

Tags: excel, filter, criteria

I have a document with columns A-AI and nearly 3000 rows, and every single cell uses formulas pulled from different sheets that use their own formulas, or pivot tables.

Currently, applying a filter on one column takes roughly 30 seconds to process. So in order to find the data I need, I need to filter 3-5 columns consecutively ultimately wasting 2 minutes every time I need to look at new data.

Is there a way that I can set the filtering criteria for each column, and *then* process the filter, to save precious minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Advanced Filter.  That allows you to add as many conditions as you want and only processes on your command.  The downside is that it won't update or un-filter until you tell it too either.

[Link to MS help page for Adv Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention as viable solution but using VBA you could just add filters and after all filters are added you apply the autofilter. Example code:

```
Sub Apply_AutoFilter()
    Dim afFilters
    Dim afCol1
    Dim afCol3

    ' Turn on AutoFilter.
    Spreadsheet1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C20").AutoFilter

    ' Set a variable to the AutoFilter object.
    Set afFilters = Spreadsheet1.Worksheets("sheet1").AutoFilter

    Set afCol1 = afFilters.Filters(1)
    Set afCol3 = afFilters.Filters(3)

    ' Add a criteria that excludes blue from column A.
    afCol1.Criteria.Add "blue"

    ' Add a criteria that excludes green from column A.
    afCol1.Criteria.Add "green"

    ' Add a criteria that excludes yellow from column c.
    afCol3.Criteria.Add "yellow"

    ' At this point, the FilterMode property is False
    ' because the AutoFilter criteria has not been applied.
    MsgBox Spreadsheet1.Worksheets("Sheet1").FilterMode

    ' Apply the criteria.
    afFilters.Apply

    ' The FilterMode property is now True since you
    ' have hidden several rows in the list.
    MsgBox Spreadsheet1.Worksheets("Sheet1").FilterMode
End Sub
```

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168763(v=office.11).aspx